# Why is this "deaf grandma" program incorrect?

Tags: ruby

This code will return the correct phrase based on whether the whole string is capitalized

```
response = ''

while response != "BYE"
    puts "What would you like deary?"
    response = gets.chomp
    if response = response.downcase
        puts "speak up!"
    else
        puts "I can hear you!"
    end
    response = gets.chomp
end
```

This code, however, always returns "speak up" regardless of whether the string entered is all lowercase or all capitalized:

```
puts "What would you like deary?"
response = gets.chomp

while response != "BYE"
    if response = response.downcase
        puts "speak up!"
    else
        puts "I can hear you!"
    end
    response = gets.chomp
end
```

I'm a little confused as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you want to test for equality (`==`), not perform assignment (`=`):

```
if response == response.downcase
```